# How Stuff Works Or Logic of Stuff & XML Path in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

My Output is correct but I want to know how actually STUFF works.

I have the simple query  which returns me total number of months between `@startDate` & `@endDate`.

I am storing that months into the the @cols by help of **STUFF**.

Query is like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ',' 
                + Quotename(CONVERT(CHAR(10), startdate, 120)) 
FROM   #tempdates
```

1. "," in the query should print before the values but it print like below O/P.
2. If I remove XML Path from the stuff I am getting null value.
3. How actually **STUFFworks with XML path**

Here's My output :

[image]

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),   
            @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  
            @startdate datetime =  '1-Jan-2014',  
            @enddate datetime  =  '1-Jun-2014'

    ;with cte (StartDate, EndDate) as   
    (   
       select min(@startdate) StartDate, max(@enddate) EndDate   
       union all   
       select dateadd(mm, 1, StartDate), EndDate   
       from cte   
       where StartDate < EndDate   
    )   
    select StartDate   
    into #tempDates   
    from cte   

    select @cols =  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), StartDate, 120))   
        from #tempDates   
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE   
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   
        ,1,1,'') 


        select @cols
        drop table #tempDates
```

Comment: Thanx for edit @Gidil but I want help to understand stuff.

Comment: To be honest I think you should capitalize the word STUFF everywhere in your post, otherwise it just seems you want to know how stuff works, you know, stuff, things, thingamajigs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Stuff and For Xml Path work in Sql Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Stuff works on strings, the only thing its doing on your SQL is remove the initial comma from position 1. Without stuff it would look like ,a,b,c,d but when you stuff the position one with an empty value it transforms it to a,b,c,d

Your question is probably more about what FOR XML is doing. In this case, the `FOR XML` is being applied as a "trick" to concatenate all the rows from `#tempDates` in one long comma-separated string ,a,b,c,d and stuff is just removing that first comma.

For xml is creating a string x = ',a' + ',b' +',c' + ',d' so x ends up as ',a,b,c,d'

`Stuff(x,1,1,'')` is replacing only the comma in position 1 to 1 with '' therefore is now x='a,b,c,d'

```
[STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )]
```

Comment: Okay I got it but if first comma is only for replacement then hoe comma is coming after the value

Comment: That's Great! Means first whole string will be form like as you have mentioned in the example then it XML will remove only first comma from it. I thought it delete comma from every row which stuff will get.

Comment: Last question : XML path is only used for concatenating the string & why this '.' is used in my query.

Comment: '.' in xml path means 'current element' so basically you are taking the value of the current element (,a,b,c,d) as nvarchar and return it to the stuff function

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Thank you for your valuable time.