# Select Comma Separate values in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

Following is the table:

[image]

I am trying to get comma separated values where **ColC** `is not Null`

**Output:**

(Sql,My),(Dev,Prod)

I am using sql `server 2012` tried `COALESCE` but failed. Please help.

Here the create and insert script:

```
create table T_MyIssue(ColA Varchar(50), ColB Varchar(50), ColC Varchar(50))

Insert Into T_MyIssue(ColA,ColB,ColC)
values('Sql','My','DB'),
('Server','MS',Null),
('Dev','Prod','Mongo')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you need, but one of these should do the job

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ColA VARCHAR(10),ColB VARCHAR(10),ColC VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Sql','My','DB')
,('Server','MS',NULL)
,('Dev','Prod','Mongo')

SELECT ISNULL(ColA,'') + ',' + ISNULL(ColB,'')
FROM @tbl AS t
WHERE ColC IS NOT NULL
```

The result

```
Sql,My
Dev,Prod
```

Or this

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',('+ ISNULL(ColA,'') + ',' + ISNULL(ColB,'') + ')'
    FROM @tbl AS t
    WHERE ColC IS NOT NULL
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'')
```

Returns

```
(Sql,My),(Dev,Prod)
```

Comment: Perfect this is what I was trying to achieve, need to go through "STUFF". Thanks

Comment: @PranayDeep `STUFF` is only needed to cut away the leading comma, The hard work is done by `FOR XML PATH('')`

Comment: Yeah, just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server .