# Join table and combine results from one into gridview

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to join 2 tables, the 1st table will return 1 row for each query, but the 2nd table has 1 or more rows that I want to combine and give a value in the one result of the 1st table. For the below dataset, I want to return only 2 rows, with VideoName 1 and 2, then the personId that each video was sent to. So Video 1 was sent to person 3 and person 4 is the first row. Video 2 was sent only to person 4.

Table 1

```
VideoId  Videoname  
1        Video1
2        Video2

Table 2

SendId   VideoId  PersonId
1         1         4
2         1         3
3         2         4
```

Desired output

```
VideoName    Sent to
 Video1      4 and 3
 Video2      4
```

Comment: Please add the desired output as table instead of describing it

Comment: Please post your expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.*,
    stuff((select distinct ' and ' + convert(varchar(10),personId) 
            from table2 t2 where t1.videoid = t2.videoId
            for xml path('')),
    1,5,'')
from table1 t1;
```

---

For more on `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`:

- [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: how do i get the result into the gridview? I tried using "personId" but it said "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'PersonId'."

Comment: I figured it out from this example and the link you provided. you have to put abc = stuff and "abc" is the value you use in the gridview. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use For Xml Path with Stuff

```
SELECT DISTINCT VIDEONAME, STUFF((SELECT ','+CAST(PERSONID AS VARCHAR(30)) FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.VIDEOID=T2.VIDEOID FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') FROM TABLE1 T1
```

Comment: how do i get the result into the gridview? I tried using "personId" but it said "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'PersonId'."

Comment: I used abc = stuff and "abc" was the value for gridview