# Removing leading zeros in a string in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove leading zeros for a varchar column. Actually we are storing version information in a column. Find below example versions.

2.00.001
The output would be : 2.0.1

Input : 2.00.00.001
The output would be: 2.0.0.1

Input : 2.00
The output would be : 2.0

The dots in the version column not constant.  It may be two or three or four

I found some solutions in google but those are not working. Find below are the queries I tried.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('2.00.001', PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', '2.00.001' + ' '), LEN('2.00.001'))

SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE('2.00.001', '0', ' ')),' ', '0')
```

Please suggest me the best approach in sqlserver.

Comment: what is the maximum amount of 0's in your version numbers?

Comment: those zeros and dots are not constant.

Comment: i think you are going to need a split string function to convert the values to numbers before putting them back together again.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a string splitting function with [`cross apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx), [`for xml path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx), and [`stuff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).
For an explanation on how stuff and for xml works together to concatenate a string from selected rows, [read this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server).

Using a string splitting function will enable you to convert each number part of the string to int, that will remove the leading zeroes. Executing a select statement on the result of the string splitting function will enable you to get your int values back into a varchar value, seperated by dot.
The stuff function will remove the first dot.

Create the string splitting function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

I've chosen to use an xml based function because it's fairly simple. If you are using 2016 version you can use the built in [`string_split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) function. For earlier versions, I would stronly suggest reading Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    col varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('2.00.001'),
('2.00.00.001'),
('2.00')
```

The query:

```
SELECT col, result
FROM @T
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT STUFF(
    (
    SELECT '.' + CAST(CAST(Item as int) as varchar(20)) 
    FROM SplitStrings_XML(col, '.')
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    , 1, 1, '') As result

) x
```

Results:

```
col             result
2.00.001        2.0.1
2.00.00.001     2.0.0.1
2.00            2.0
```

You can see it in action on [this link on rextester](http://rextester.com/WICQB67246)

Comment: doesn't work for this: `DECLARE @val AS NVARCHAR(20) = '2.00.00.001';
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@val, '00', '><'), '<>', ''), '><', '0') as string`

Comment: @Tanner I've changed my answer to a completly different approach.

Comment: FYI – for this specific case (version numbers separated by dots) there is simpler solution with less unnecessary overhead which also performs faster. I have added it as [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42134488/2392157). Still your solution can be useful for programmers learning those classic SQL Server tricks with strings.

Answer (score 1):

No need for Split/Parse Function, and easy to expand if there could be more than 5 groups

```
Declare @YourTable table (YourCol varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable Values
('2.00.001'),
('2.00.00.001'),
('2.00')

Update @YourTable
       Set YourCol = concat(Pos1,'.'+Pos2,'.'+Pos3,'.'+Pos4,'.'+Pos5)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','int')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','int')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','int')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','int')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','int')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.YourCol,'.','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B

Select * from @YourTable
```

Returns

```
YourCol
2.0.1
2.0.0.1
2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Easy, fast, compatible and readable way – without tables or XML tricks.

Correctly handles all cases including empty string, `NULL`, or numbers like `00100`.
Supports unlimited number of groups. Runs on all SQL Server versions.

- Step 1: Remove leading zeros from all groups.
- Step 2: Place single zero to groups where no digits remained.

*[Edit: Not sure why it was downvoted twice. Check the solution:* ]

---

**The function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fncGetNormalizedVersionNumber(@Version nvarchar(200))
    RETURNS nvarchar(200) AS
BEGIN
    -- Preprocessing: Surround version string by dots so all groups have the same format.
    SET @Version = '.' + @Version + '.';

    -- Step 1: Remove any leading zeros from groups as long as string length decreases.
    DECLARE @PreviousLength int = 0;
    WHILE @PreviousLength <> LEN(@Version)
    BEGIN
        SET @PreviousLength = LEN(@Version);
        SET @Version = REPLACE(@Version, '.0', '.');
    END;

    -- Step 2: Insert 0 to any empty group as long as string length increases.
    SET @PreviousLength = 0;
    WHILE @PreviousLength <> LEN(@Version)
    BEGIN
        SET @PreviousLength = LEN(@Version);
        SET @Version = REPLACE(@Version, '..', '.0.');
    END;

    -- Strip leading and trailing dot added by preprocessing.
    RETURN SUBSTRING(@Version, 2, LEN(@Version) - 2);
END;
```

**Usage:**

```
SELECT dbo.fncGetNormalizedVersionNumber('020.00.00.000100');
```

> 20.0.0.100

**Performance per 100,000 calculations:**

- [solution using helper function + helper tables + XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42133095/2392157): **54519 ms**
- this solution (used on table column): **2574 ms** (→ **21** times faster) (UPDATED after [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132704/removing-leading-zeros-in-a-string-in-sqlserver/42134488?noredirect=1#comment71446058_42134488).)

Comment: While this solution might work faster for a single string variable, It's not going to be easy to scale it to work with all rows in a table. Also, It will not handle the `2.00` -> `2.0` requested by the OP correctly. It will convert it to `2.`

Comment: @ZoharPeled – maybe you made a mistake in your guess, beucase the program gives `2.00` → `2.0`.  Performance on table column is 21 times better than performance of the linked overhead solution (metric updated). Not mentioning lesser mental effort on decoding the source by human.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2016:

`SELECT
    STUFF
    ((SELECT
            '.' + CAST(CAST(value AS INT) AS VARCHAR)
        FROM STRING_SPLIT('2.00.001', '.')
        FOR XML PATH (''))
    , 1, 1, '')`

According to this: https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split

It's the fastest way :)
Aaron Bertrand knows it's stuff.

For an interesting and deep read about splitting strings on SQL Server plese read this gem of knowledge: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

It has some clever strategies

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SUBSTRING(str_col, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', str_col+'.'), LEN(str_col))
```

Comment: select SUBSTRING('2.00.001', PATINDEX('%[^0]%', '2.00.001'+'.'), LEN('2.00.001'))

Comment: Output is giving: 2.00.001. but i need 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for but you can give a go, it should handle up to 4 zeros.

```
DECLARE @VERSION NVARCHAR(20) = '2.00.00.001'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@VERSION, '0000','0'),'000','0'),'00','0')
```

2.0.0.01

```
SET @VERSION = '2.00.00.01'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@VERSION, '0000','0'),'000','0'),'00','0')
```

2.0.0.01

```
SET @VERSION = '2.000.0000.0001'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@VERSION, '0000','0'),'000','0'),'00','0')
```

2.0.0.01

Comment: Do we want to create `10` from `100`?

Comment: @miroxlav, Not shoure what you are about here? Did you  test it? I just noticed it will not remove zeros before last grater than zero digit, but I am working on it

Comment: Try with `SET @VERSION = '2.000.0000.100'`. It leads to incorrect result.

Comment: Question is about to remove leading zeros so make 1 from 001, not 1 from 100.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, input is a version number. Your solution will work only on when any part of the version number will not exceed 99. But would you place solution with such a special constraint into your own source code?

Comment: No I wouldn't, It was only "not perfect" idea how to resolve an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(s VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO  #tt VALUES
('2.00.001'),
('2.00.00.001'),
('2.00')

SELECT t.s,STUFF(c.s,1,1,'') AS news FROM #tt AS t
OUTER APPLY(
       SELECT '.'+LTRIM(z.n) FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(XML,'<n>'+REPLACE(t.s,'.','</n><n>')+'</n>'))) x(xs)
       CROSS APPLY(SELECT n.value('.','int') FROM x.xs.nodes('n') AS y(n)) z(n)
       FOR XML PATH('')
) c(s)
```

```
s               news
--------------- -----------
2.00.001        2.0.1
2.00.00.001     2.0.0.1
2.00            2.0
```