# Combine Fields Value with Subquery Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I created a view with the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT InventoryID, AccountCode, Description, Notes + N'N ' +
            (SELECT Deployment
            FROM    dbo.Deployment
            WHERE (dbo.Inventory.InventoryID = InventoryID)) AS Remarks
FROM   dbo.Inventory
```

But this returns an error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows.`

Here's the table structure and the sample output that I'd like:

[image]

Is it possible to concatenate the value of `Notes` field with the subquery that has multiple values?

Update:

Here's the error. I also include the database structure in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `Notes` that's causing the problem, it's the `Deployment`. More accuractly, it's the fact that you have multiple rows in the deployment table with the same inventory id. 
You can use `STUFF` and `FOR XML` to return a single result of concatenated string from the subquery, like this:

```
SELECT  InventoryID, 
        AccountCode, 
        Description, 
        Notes + N'N ' +
        (
            SELECT STUFF(
                (SELECT ',' + Deployment
                FROM dbo.Deployment
                WHERE t.InventoryID = InventoryID
                FOR XML PATH(''))
                , 1, 1, '')
        ) AS Remarks
 FROM   dbo.Inventory t
```

For an explanation on how stuff and for xml works together to concatenate a string from selected rows, read [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I encounter this error `Error in WHERE clause near '('. Error in FROM clause: near 'Inventory'. Unable to parse query text.`

Comment: Still got the error `Error in WHERE clause near '('. Error in FROM clause: near 't'. Unable to parse query text.`

Comment: I saw your code on the link and it is working. Why it doesn't work on my computer? Please see my updated post. I include my database structure in the image.

Comment: I have no idea. Try to execute the query in a "new query" pane, not the "create view" pane, see what happens.

Comment: Yes, it works on new query. But I'd like to save this on view so I can create a report based on view.

Comment: Then just add `CREATE VIEW <view name> AS` on top... SSMS's designers are known for being bad, you should get used to write your create views manually.