# T-SQL Concat 2 Rows with same Id from Join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working on a query in T-SQL on SQL Server 2012. I gather several Titles from a table via a join from another table. My tables look like this:

Table Project:

```
 ProjectId |
-----------+
1          |   
2          |   
3          |
```

Table ProjectResources

```
ResourceId |    Label      | ProjectId
-----------+---------------+-----------
2          |   Resource X  |  1 
3          |   Resource Y  |  1
4          |   Resource Z  |  2
5          |   Resource A  |  2
6          |   Resource X  |  3
```

the **desired output** in my temporary table should look like this:

```
ProjectId  |   Label                  |
-----------+--------------------------+
1          |   Resource X, Resource Y |
2          |   Resource Z, Resource A |
3          |   Resource X             |
```

I want to concat all Labels with the same ProjectId. My current query looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpProjects
(
    ProjectId INT
    , Label VARCHAR(1000)
)

SELECT [P].ProjectId, [PR].Label 
    INTO #tmpProjects
FROM [MySchema].[ProjectResources] [PR]
INNER JOIN dbo.Project [P] ON [P].ProjectId= [PR].ProjectId
```

Unfortunatly my query creates a new row for each Resouce Label. Do you know how to create a new temp table with "concatinated" merged rows for each resource holding the same ProjectId?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are asking how to concatenate columns,  not rows. There are various techniques, described and benchmarked in  [Grouped Concatenation in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) by Aaron Bertrand. The fastest technique uses SQLCLR, the second fastest XML. `STRING_AGG` will be supported natively in the next version of SQL Server, SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**For xml path**, **stuff**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server) like this

```
SELECT p.ProjectId,
     STUFF((     SELECT ', ' + pr.Label 
            FROM ProjectResources pr 
            WHERE  pr.ProjectId = p.ProjectId FOR XML PATH('')
           )
         ,1,2,'') as Label
FROM Project p
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and the good hint, I did some research and apparently For Xml path is a very fast solution for this common problem. :)

Comment: You are welcome ...

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table2
    ([ResourceId] int, [Label] varchar(10), [ProjectId] int)
INSERT INTO #Table2
    ([ResourceId], [Label], [ProjectId])
VALUES
    (2, 'Resource X', 1),
    (3, 'Resource Y', 1),
    (4, 'Resource Z', 2),
    (5, 'Resource A', 2),
    (6, 'Resource X', 3)
SELECT p.ProjectId,
     STUFF((     SELECT ', ' + pr.Label 
            FROM (select a.ProjectId,ResourceId,Label from #Table1 A join #Table2 B on a.ProjectId=b.ProjectId) pr 
            WHERE  pr.ProjectId = p.ProjectId FOR XML PATH('')
           )
         ,1,2,'') as Label
FROM (select a.ProjectId,ResourceId,Label from #Table1 A join #Table2 B on a.ProjectId=b.ProjectId) p
group by  p.ProjectId

output 

ProjectId  |   Label                  |
-----------+--------------------------+
1          |   Resource X, Resource Y |
2          |   Resource Z, Resource A |
3          |   Resource X             |
```

Comment: A code-only answer isn't considered a good answer. Please explain *why* this code answers the question. This is just one of the techniques available to aggregate strings and it's not even the fastest one