# SSRS Turning a column into a comma delineated list grouped by another column

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have data from a SQL query that looks like the table on the left but I want to use SSRS to make it look like the table on the right. Is this possible?

[image: output]

I'm willing to modify the SQL if neccesary, assume it is currently of the form

```
SELECT

Name
,Capital Visited

From 

Trips
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` for this combined with `XML PATH` functions as follows.

It looks a bit lengthy but it includes sample data matching your sample so you can test it before you apply it to your real tables.

```
DECLARE @trips TABLE([Name] varchar(50), [Capital Visited] varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @trips
VALUES
('Joe', 'London'),
('Fred', 'Tokyo'),
('Joe', 'Berlin'),
('Bob', 'Paris'),
('Fred', 'London'),
('Fred', 'Madrid'),
('Bob', 'Rome')

/* Uncomment below to check the table data looks as expected */
-- SELECT [Name] ,[Capital Visited] From @trips

SELECT DISTINCT
    [Name], cx.Captials
    FROM
        @trips t
        CROSS APPLY (   SELECT Stuff(
                        (
                        SELECT ', ' + [Capital Visited]
                        FROM @trips WHERE [Name] = t.[Name]
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '') AS Captials
                    ) cx
```

This gives you following results

```
Name        Captials
Bob         Paris, Rome
Fred        Tokyo, London, Madrid
Joe         London, Berlin
```

Rather than me explaining the answer in full, there is a reasonable explaination here.

[How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

As an SSRS solution, you can **combine Join and LookupSet** to concatenate all the values in a group. Within a table grouped by `NAME`, use this expression:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!NAME.Value, Fields!NAME.Value, Fields!CAPITAL_VISITED.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

`LookupSet()` gets you all the values from a dataset based on a primary key and returns them as an array. (It's typically used to get values from a different dataset, but in this case we use just one). `Join()` then concatenates all the values found the array using a chosen delimiter (", ").

Comment: I accepted Alans answer because it was the one I used (it was first) but thanks for this I think it will be useful for the future.