# How to combine the multiple lines of data of a single column of data base into one line while retrieving or after retrieving. I am using JDBC

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

How to combine the multiple lines of data of a single column of data base into one line while retrieving or after retrieving. I am using JDBC to retrieve the data.

Below is example

Column `address` is stored as below in database and when retrieved and populated in Excel also it is populated in different rows of the column (different cells)

```
plot-22, xyz
Bangalore
Karnataka
521638
```

after retrieving the data from data base I have to put it in a excel file as below in one cell

```
plot-22, xyz Bangalore Karnataka 521638
```

I have tried many ways but not able remove the escape line and combine into one line.

I am using SQL Server database.

Comment: It would be better if you could also add what you have tried.

Comment: add your sample data with table structure model

Comment: Are these plot-22, xyz are column names ?

Comment: @Sneha - I have tried below code but not working     if(coulumn24!=null)
      {
       
        String nline = coulumn24.replace("\\n","");
      
      fw.append(nline);
      }

Comment: @Srini - plot22,xyz  is the value in one row of the column address, table look like below                                                                                    
 Name  ID         Address
  sam  1234 plot-22, xyz
                                Bangalore
                                 Karnataka
                                 521638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution. We need to append  double quote (")to the string to remove next line character

```
{
String values = rs.getString(j);
char ch = '"';
String nvalues = ch + values + ch; // To escape the next line character

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use STUFF function, it's a bit tricky and you have to care about the order in which you have to put all the records that form the address. Something like this can work:

```
declare @addr varchar(MAX)

SET @addr = STUFF( (SELECT ',' + [Address] FROM Table_1 WHERE Cust_ID = 1 
ORDER BY sub_id FOR XML PATH('')    ), 1, 1, '') 

print @dir
```

This thread is very useful to understand how stuff works:

[How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will be easy like:
A `PIVOT` used to rotate the data from one column into multiple columns

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot