# Why does using XML Path('') return a blue underlined data and how to remove it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I am using this to concatenate different strings into one and it works but problem is that it is UNDERLINED and BLUE like a link and I tried removing it but nothing works. Also, column header is something not presentable.

```
SELECT  np.Name+ ', ' AS 'data()' 
        FROM NewsPaper np
        inner join NitNewsPaper nitnp
        on nitnp.NewsPaper_ID= np.NewPaperID  
        where Nit_NO= 1518
        FOR XML PATH('')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below query. It should fix your issue.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + np.NAME
FROM NewsPaper np
INNER JOIN NitNewsPaper nitnp ON nitnp.NewsPaper_ID = np.NewPaperID
WHERE Nit_NO = 1518
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as 'data'
```

`FOR XML PATH` allows you to output the results of the query as XML and hence you are seeing the blue underline. This will output something like: `, Name1, Name2`. We need to get rid of the leading  `', '` from this. So, we use STUFF to remove the first 2 characters.

Comment: changed the answer. Check now

Comment: STUFF requires 4 args

Comment: forgot to add a select before np.name. Check now

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen okay. I am updating answer.

Comment: @Stacky updated the answer with some explanations. Here's a similar answer with an elaborate explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212160/3082296