# How can I obtain all rows from this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I return the values i want?

I know the distinct value is messing up result but dont know how to fix

```
Declare @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
Declare @today as date; Set @today = getdate();

Select distinct @ColumnNames +=  QuoteName(cast(date as varchar(100))) + ','
From Dates
where date >= @today

Print @ColumnNames
```

Results are

```
[2017-10-17],
```

but should be

```
[2017-10-11],[2017-10-12],[2017-10-13],[2017-10-14],[2017-10-15],[2017-10-16],[2017-10-17],
```

Comment: Your code is SQL Server code, so I changed the tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '+',use coalesce and use distinct before using coalesce.Note in my case the where clause is `where date > 2017-10-04`

```
select distinct convert(varchar(10),date,23) as new_date
into #temp1
from dates

declare @columnnames nvarchar(max)
select  @columnnames =  coalesce(@columnnames+ ', ', '') + new_date 
from #temp1  

drop table #temp1
print @columnnames
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This method may fail. Try adding `distinct` in `select` it will fail sometimes.  Always use  for xml path('') to concatenate rows to csv