# MySQL Inner Join Merge Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem: I have three tables, a users table, a categories table and a user_category table which connects the two first tables with foregn keys.

**users table:**

```
id     username

1      user1
...    ...
```

**categories table:**

```
id    category

1     test1
2     test2
3     test3
...   ...
```

**user_category table**

```
id    user_id    category_id
1     1          1
2     1          2
3     1          3
```

Now I want to select all users with their categories, but I dont want to have multiple rows of the same user - instead, I want to merge all categories of a user into one category field.

```
SELECT users.*, categories.category FROM user_category INNER JOIN users ON users.id = user_category.user_id LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = user_category.category_id
```

**The output:**

```
 id     username     category
 1      user1        test1
 1      user1        test2
 1      user1        test3
```

But I want the following:

```
 id     username     category
 1      user1        test1, test2, test3
```

Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: `test1, test2, test3` you shouldn't do that and should learn how to normalize your db

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCAT and group by username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.category) as cats
FROM user_category 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = user_category.user_id 
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = user_category.category_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.username
```

could do what you want.

See http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/group_concat

With TSQL you can use smth like [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: The problem is, that I just get one category for the user instead of all.

Comment: @pete It does work, here you have a working example: http://rextester.com/MTZROD6195 *Note: I had to change `users` to `usersx` so it would run on rextester*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know what was wrong, but it works now.