# SQL query syntax for loop (Classic ASP)

Tags: sql, asp-classic

[image]I have 4 tables and the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Synola, dbo.Stores, dbo.Fpa, dbo.Nomismata
WHERE
dbo.Stores.Store_id = dbo.Synola.Store_id
AND
dbo.Stores.fpa_id = dbo.Fpa.fpa_id
AND
dbo.Stores.nomisma_id = dbo.Nomismata.nomisma_id
```

The above works fine and without errors.

My problem is that when I am trying to **loop** the above query:

Currently, in my Stores TABLE, I have **only 2 stores** and I want in the loop to get results **ONLY** for 2 records. The 2 records with my 2 stores. But unfortunately I am receiving more than 2 records.

Which is the correct syntax of my query in a way to receive results only for my **2 stores** in the loop?

Comment: What year is it?  Please use the modern syntax, if possible.

Comment: If you're getting more than 2 result rows then there are *multiple* matching rows in these other tables. How are *we* or your SQL system meant to know *which* rows to pick from the other tables for each store? Examine your data, formulate *specific* rules based on the *data* stored in these other tables for how to pick one row per store and then, if it's not clear how to integrate those rules into your query, at least *add them to your question*. Sample data wouldn't hurt either when you're adding the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should only retrieve data that's available in ALL tables.  Therefore, it there's not a match to the main `Stores` table, then the result wont show.

```
SELECT *
FROM Stores s
JOIN Synola sy ON sy.Store_id = s.Store_id
JOIN Fpa f ON f.fpa_id = s.fpa_id
JOIN Nomismata n ON n.nomisma_id = s.nomisma_id
```

If you are getting more rows because there are more matches in other tables, then you need to look into adding more `WHERE` conditions or using another type of `JOIN`.

More info: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Edit: To see where you are getting multiple matches on your `JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.Store_id "Store_id from Store",
    ,sy.Store_id "Store_id from Synola"
    ,s.fpa_id "fpa_id from Store"
    ,f.fpa_id "fpa_id from Fpa"
    ,s.nonisma_id "nomisma_id from Store"   
    ,n.nonisma_id "nomisma_id from Nomismata"
FROM Stores s
JOIN Synola sy ON sy.Store_id = s.Store_id
JOIN Fpa f ON f.fpa_id = s.fpa_id
JOIN Nomismata n ON n.nomisma_id = s.nomisma_id
```

Comment: Again I am receiving more than 2 records. I have posted also an image with my tables structure..

Comment: @user2986570 Then you are getting more than one match in `Synola`, `Fpa`, or `Nomismata` in the `ON` part of the `JOIN`.  Either don't `JOIN` some of those tables if you don't have to, or add a `WHERE` condition to filter out the matches you don't want.

Comment: @user2986570 I added an additional snippet to help you find which table is getting the multiple matches. Technically, this is just to give you a visual.  Because of how this type of join works, there is a multiple match in all three.

Comment: I am getting multiple matches from the table Synola

Comment: @user2986570 Okay, so at this point you need to add a condition to your `WHERE` clause to filter out the rows from Synola that you don't want.  That, or don't join Synola if you don't have to for your needs i.e. you don't need any of the information from it.

Comment: I need all the information of table Synola! From the table Stores i need only the Store_Name, from the table Fpa i need only the fpa_pososto and from the table Nomismata i need only the nomisma

Comment: @user2986570 So you're saying that you need to make multiple rows from Synola into one row? You would have to do something like `STUFF`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server However, it's clear you should look into some of the basics of a relational database. That way this will be a bit easier to understand why you're getting the result you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your advice.

Comment: @justiceorjustus - `STUFF` is used to *remove a comma from the final result*. Whereas `FOR XML PATH` actually takes all of the separate results and concatenates them together. Thinking of that technique as being `STUFF` is to entirely focus on the wrong part.