# SQL Server Stuff based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my current table.

```
ImageID    Brand     Segment
101        Kitkat     Biscuit
101        Galaxy     Biscuit
102        Kitkat     Chocolate
102        Kitkat     Chocolate
103        Kitkat     Chocolate
103        Twix       Ice Cream
```

My desired table

```
ImageID    Brand             Segment
101        Kitkat,Galaxy     Biscuit
102        Kitkat            Chocolate
103        Kitkat, Twix      Chocolate, Ice Cream
```

I'm trying to group by `ImageID`. In such a way that if an `ImageID` has multiple records. Then 
`Brand` and `Segment` will be stuff, but not repeated [Ref: 102, Kitkat & Chocolate word didn't get repeated]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005 sound right?  Group_concat is the usual term for this, I beleive you need to fake it in MSSQL

Comment: In record 103. I have kitkat brand & twix.
In segment i have choclate & ice cream.
So basically i want to stuff both of the values

Comment: @Twelfth let me check, but seems ur guiding me to the right path let me check that also. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server might be better, uses the stuff function.  Googling MSSQL 2008 group_concat gives tons of info.  Apparently 2017 has a better function for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`STUFF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server) is a common SQL Server approach for this:

```
SELECT T.ImageID,
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Brand
             FROM yourTable T2
             WHERE T2.ImageID= T.ImageID
             FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') Brand,
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Segment
             FROM yourTable T2
             WHERE T2.ImageID= T.ImageID
             FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') Segment
FROM yourTable T
GROUP BY T.ImageID
```