# Universal/Dynamic SQL function to take any table and concatenate values to strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

[image]

Trying to take existing [solutions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) and abstract it so I dont have to rewrite code each time. I imagine this must exist already but I only been able to find custom implementations. Picturing fn_tableToConcatStrings( tbl Table)

Comment: Answer here varies between databases.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264626/sql-server-stuff-based-on-condition#comment85532740_49264626 is a question from yesterday that covers the Microsoft answer (and even that answer depends on what version of MSSQL you are using)

Comment: Was looking for something more abstract that will apply to any table regardless fields. Thanks though

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-aggregation+sql)

Comment: Gotcha, sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I used the built in LISTAGG function in Oracle to do this all the time. This function is only available I think in Oracle 10g and above. 
 You can see the documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030