# Query to combine the table (with subquery or so) to reduce data redundant

Tags: sql-server

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be8Jk.png)
what is the query to make the data in [DiagnosisName] table became one like (name1 , name2) so the [PatientName] table didn't show redundant.

[Result I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux3Aw.png)

Comment: look for `stuff for xml`

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far. Also, putting your input and desired results directly in the question instead of as images is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry im new to this forum 

This is my query to show [Diagnosis Name]
--There is query to select registrationNo, etc--
(SELECT d.DiagnosisName + ',' 
       FROM Diagnosis dd
       WHERE dd.DiagnosisName = d.DiagnosisName
       GROUP BY dd.DiagnosisName
       FOR XML PATH('')) [Diagnosis Name]
From Registration r
--Inner join stuff etc-
 INNER  JOIN EpisodeDiagnosis ed
            ON  ed.RegistrationNo = r.RegistrationNo
       INNER  JOIN Diagnosis d
            ON  d.DiagnosisCode = ed.DiagnosisCode
GROUP BY d.DiagnosisName

Comment: you need to find better examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following.

```
SELECT *,
STUFF((SELECT ',' + DiagnosisName 
            FROM   [Table_Name] T1 
            WHERE  T1.RegistrationNo = T2.RegistrationNo 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')     
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT 
       RegistrationNo, 
       MedicalNo, 
       PatientName, 
       Gender, 
       Umur, 
       [Bed No], 
       [Payer Type]         
   FROM   [Table_Name] 
) T2
```