# Create a sparse matrix from observations

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am new to SQL server, I am a R user but R can't be used with my huge dataset (not enough memory).

### What I want to do:

I want to create a sparse matrix from a table with only 2 columns, I dont have any value column, it seems easy but I didn't find the right way to do it.

### My data:

```
ID_patient | ID_product
-----------------------
123            A
123            B
111            C
222            A
333            D
333            E
```

### Ouput  wanted:

```
ID_patient |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |
----------------------------------------------------
123            1       1
111                            1
222            1
333                                    1       1
```

I have read that I can use the GROUP BY function or Pivot feature but what I have tried so far failed.

### Edit

I don't know all the products, so the right way to do that is by using **dynamic pivot** ?

Comment: It is a simple PIVOT/conditional aggregation. Please post your attempts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will look for this feature then.

Comment: There are any number of examples if you search on "T-SQL PIVOT" or "T-SQL Crosstab"

Comment: Here what I have found as dynimac sql :

`declare @col nvarchar(max), @query nvarchar(max)

select @col = stuff(
                      (select ','+quotename(id_product) from dbo.table for xml path('')),
                       1,1, '')

set @query =   N'select * from
                (
                  select * from dbo.table
                )a 
                PIVOT
                (
                  MAX(id_patient) for id_product in ('+@col+')
                )pvt'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like **[PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)**

<kbd>**[See demo](http://rextester.com/VLTKY89579)**</kbd>

```
Select * from 
(select *, copy=Id_product from t)t
pivot
(
    count(copy) for ID_product in ([A],[B],[C],[D],[E]))p
```

If you don't know A, B, C, D, .. before hand then you should go for dynamic pivot

update:
<kbd>**[updated dynamic piv demo](http://rextester.com/JIRD63002)**</kbd>

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max) 

select @cols=  Stuff((select ','+  quotename( ID_product) from
      (select distinct id_product from t) t  for xml path ('')),1,1,'')

select @query='Select * from 
( select *, copy=Id_product from t ) t
pivot
(count(copy) for ID_product in ( '+@cols+' ))p '
  exec(@query)
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed, I need to use dynamic pivot.

Comment: That's perfect, I need to learn this dynamic way to code !
Thank you very much sir !

Comment: @Alexandregeorges I'd recommend this SO question for gaining knowledge [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp')IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Temp

DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (ID_patient INT, ID_product varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT 123,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 123,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 111,'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 222,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 333,'D' UNION ALL
SELECT 333,'E'  


SELECT * INTO #Temp 
    FROM @temp
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @Col  nvarchar(max),
        @Col2  nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Col=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME(ID_product) FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
SELECT @Col2=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+'ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(ID_product)+','' '') AS '+QUOTENAME(ID_product) FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql='
SELECT ID_patient,'+@Col2+'
FROM
(
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK()OVER( PARTITION BY ID_patient ORDER By ID_patient) AS [Val] FROM #Temp
)AS Src
PIVOT 
(MAX(Val) FOR ID_product IN ('+@Col+')
)AS PVT '
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result

```
ID_patient  A   B   C   D   E
------------------------------
111         0   0   1   0   0
123         1   1   0   0   0
222         1   0   0   0   0
333         0   0   0   1   1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I should have specified I cant use hard code (I dont know all the products).

Comment: dynamic sql required then

Comment: @Alexandregeorges Just now updated script using dynamic sql

Comment: Thank you for your help but the DhruvJoshi code is easier !