# T-SQL (SQL Server): Extract unique sets/groups of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using T-SQL, how would I extract the unique sets from a table using SQL.  Here is a sample table:

```
ID  Value
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   A
2   B
2   C
3   D
3   E
4   D
4   E
5   X
5   Y
5   Z
6   Q
7   Q
8   Q
9   Q
10  A
```

In this case, the desired result set would have five unique sets as follows:

```
A
B
C

D
E

X
Y
Z

Q

A
```

This is representative of incoming data that I must transform.  The incoming data has hundreds of repetitive sets like this.  There is substantial value in identifying these sets; putting them into a separate table; assigning them a SetID; and then associating the core data to the relevant set based on a SetID JOIN; etc.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And what would the sets look like if you had, say, "10 A"?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have 2017 you can use stuff with xml path.
for example

```
drop table t
go
create table t(ID  int ,Value varchar(1));
go
insert into t values
(1 ,  'A'),
(1 ,  'B'),
(1 ,  'C'),
(2 ,  'A'),
(2 ,  'B'),
(2 ,  'C'),
(3 ,  'D'),
(3 ,  'E'),
(4 ,  'D'),
(4 ,  'E'),
(5 ,  'X'),
(5 ,  'Y'),
(5 ,  'Z'),
(6 ,  'Q'),
(7 ,  'Q'),
(8 ,  'Q'),
(9 ,  'Q'),
(10,  'A');
```

To get a rows of sets

```
select  distinct 
        maskdetail = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + t1.value
          FROM t t1
          WHERE t1.id = t.id
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from t

maskdetail
------------------------------
A
A,B,C
D,E
Q
X,Y,Z

(5 row(s) affected)
```

To get a column of sets

```
select t.value 
from t 
join
(
select  min(id) minid,maskdetail
from
(
select  distinct t.id,
        maskdetail = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + t1.value
          FROM t t1
          WHERE t1.id = t.id
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from t
) s
group by maskdetail
) x
on x.minid = t.id

value
-----
A
A
B
C
D
E
Q
X
Y
Z

(10 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Well, since you already mentioned MSSQL 2017, then might as well show how to do this via STRING_AGG ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS has a group_concat/listagg funtion it's simple

```
select distinct group_concat(value order by value)
from tab
group by id
```

Comment: I should have noted that I am using T-SQL, which does not have such a function.

Great answer.  Sorry for my omission.

Comment: @digest806: Well, there's STRING_AGG in SQLServer 2017 :-) Before you have to use FOR XML plus STUFF, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server