# How to join values in one column? (SQL Server 2008R2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregation

I don't know how to describe my problem shortly in the title but I hope someone will understand it and can try to help me :)

In my case I have 2 tables which I join:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t1.Group
FROM tblOne AS t1
UNION
SELECT t2.Name, t2.Group
FROM tblTwo AS t2
```

Result:

```
=====================
Name     |     Group
=====================
Miller   |     TST
Miller   |     DEV
Johnson  |     TST
White    |     TST
Lopez    |     DEV
Brown    |     TST
Jackson  |     DEV
Jackson  |     TST
```

## Target:

```
Name     |     Group
=====================
Miller   |     DEV, TST
Johnson  |     TST
White    |     TST
Lopez    |     DEV
Brown    |     TST
Jackson  |     DEV, TST
```

Have someone an idea?
Thanks in advance for any tip.

Comment: https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-comma-separated-value-to-rows-and-vice-versa-in-sql-server.html

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212160/9676724)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pretty much simple `xml` method with `stuff()` function :

```
select t1.name, stuff((select distinct ','+t2.[group] 
                       from table2 t2
                       where t2.name = t1.name
                       for xml path('')
                       ), 1, 1, ''
                     ) as [group]
from table1 t1 
group by name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use `FOR XML` but if your data is as it looks in your sample then you could also go for a much simpler query, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(t1.[Name], t2.[Name]) AS [Name],
    ISNULL(t1.[Group] + CASE WHEN t2.[Group] IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE '' END, '') 
        + ISNULL(t2.[Group], '') AS [Group]
FROM 
    tblOne AS t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN tblTwo AS t2 ON t2.[Name] = t1.[Name];
```

This assumes that each "Name" exists either:

- only in tblOne;
- only in tblTwo;
- exactly once in tblOne and tblTwo.

If the above logic is incorrect then you would need the XML version instead.

Also, I just have to say that using reserved names like `[Name]` and `[Group]` as column names is probably a bad idea (particular `[Group]`!)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need:

```
with t as (
      select t1.Name, Group as grp
      from tblOne
      union
      select t2.Name, Group as grp
      from tblTwo t2
     )
select name,
       stuff( (select ',' + grp
               from t t2
               where t2.name = t.name
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as groups
from (select distinct name from t) t;
```