# Group SQL rows with same column value into one row?

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

Is it possible to group SQL rows with the same column value into one row?

[image: Simple table to demonstrate what I mean]

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: In Postgres you can use `string_agg()` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-aggregation+sql) for answers to this question for various DBMS products

Answer (score 0):

For Postgresql string_agg
For Mysql use GROUP_CONCAT
Please try i.e mysql

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS( ':', title, Number )
SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Title
FROM
    example        
GROUP BY ID
```