# Replicating VBA solution in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, transpose, countif

I have a SQL query that provides me with the output in the 'Output Before' pic.
Column 5 if essentially doing a `countif` on column1 for items in column1, similar to Excel.
I would like to add some code/sub query, so that the output becomes like the 'Output After' pic.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?
I can do it in excel with VBA but just cant get my head around how to do it in SQL.

Output Before
[image: Output Before]

Output After
[image: Output After]

Comment: Always helps when asking a database question to state what type of database you're working with.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Sever Management Studio

Comment: That's the software you're using to access the database.  Not the database/version.

Comment: SQL Server 17. New to this sorry.

Comment: What should the output look like if you had different values in `column2` for `Dave`?

Comment: Whatever the values in column2 are when the original output is created, they will stay the same in the final output

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2017 you can get what you want with `STRING_AGG`:

```
select column1, column2, string_agg(column3, '&') as column3, column4
from outputbefore
group by column1, column2, column4
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to concatenate multiple rows into a single value. Your options depend on your version of SQL Server. In older versions (I think 2005+) you have to use a torturous XML procedure. Run this on your server and you'll see how it works, but I'll leave it to you to work out the query for your data:

```
SELECT  STUFF( 
     (SELECT    ', <' + name + '>'
      FROM      sys.databases
      WHERE     database_id > 4
      ORDER BY  name
        FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                  ROOT('MyString') ,
                  TYPE 
     ).value('/MyString[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS namelist;
```

As of SQL 2017 you can use the STRING_AGG function, explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

As I see this is a string concatenation issue. I used a replace to handle the character & in XML.

```
select a.col1, Col3=replace(stuff((SELECT '#' + b.col3 AS 'data()'
FROM OutputBefore) b 
where b.Col1=a.Col1
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),'#','&')
from (select distinct Col1 from OutputBefore) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by forpas and Russell, as of SQL 2017 you're able to use STRING_AGG function.

For SQL 2008+
Refer back to this:

[How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

In your case you want the delimiter to be '&' which will cause a problem with FOR XML PATH due to XML Special character. So you'll want to escape XML Special characters, example:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (Col1 NVARCHAR(10), Col2 INT, Col3 NVARCHAR(10), Col4 

NVARCHAR(10), Col5 INT)

INSERT INTO @TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
VALUES  ('Dave'     , 24    , 'house'   , 'married'     , 2)
    ,   ('Dave'     , 24    , 'car'     , 'married'     , 2)
    ,   ('Bob'      , 32    , 'House'   , 'single'      , 1)
    ,   ('George'   , 12    , 'house'   , 'divorced'    , 1)

SELECT
        t2.Col1
    ,   t2.Col2
    ,   STUFF   (   (   SELECT '&' + Col3 -- Adding '&' as delimited
                        FROM @TableA t1
                        WHERE t1.Col2 = t2.Col2
                        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''-- To escape special characters
                ) AS Col3
    ,   t2.Col4
FROM @TableA AS t2

GROUP BY    t2.Col1
        ,   t2.Col2
        ,   t2.Col4
```