# merge data in SQL with data in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have temporary table with data

```
    count1  serverinfo  csdversion  extend  servicepackdate piecolor
26  Microsoft Windows 8.1 Entreprise        NULL    2023-07-11  green
1   Microsoft® Windows Vista™ Enterprise        NULL    2010-04-13  black
2   Microsoft® Windows Vista™ Entreprise        NULL    2010-04-13  black
31698   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise  Service Pack 1  NULL    2020-04-13  green
9918    Microsoft Windows 7 Entreprise  Service Pack 1  NULL    2020-04-13  green
```

please find snapshot

i need to merge Microsoft windows 7 enterprise & Microsoft windows 7 entreprise
can you please tell me how

[image]

main query from where data is coming from SCCM tables

```
    declare @variable varchar
create table #temptable(count1 int,serverinfo varchar(max),csdversion varchar(max),extend date,servicepackdate date,piecolor varchar(max))
insert into #temptable(count1,serverinfo,csdversion,extend,servicepackdate,piecolor)
select count(distinct OS.resourceid) as ModelCount,serverinfo,dt.Servicepack,dt.extendedsupportEnddate,dt.servicepacksupportenddate,
case
when DATEDIFF(month,getdate(), dt.servicepacksupportenddate) < 0 then 'black'
when DATEDIFF(month,getdate(),dt.servicepacksupportenddate) > 0 and DATEDIFF(month, getdate(),dt.servicepacksupportenddate) < 6  then 'red'
when DATEDIFF(month,getdate(),dt.servicepacksupportenddate) > 6 and DATEDIFF(month, getdate(),dt.servicepacksupportenddate) < 12  then 'orange'
when DATEDIFF(month,getdate(),dt.servicepacksupportenddate) > 12  then 'green'
ELSE ''
End As PieColor 
 from [dbo].[v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM] OS
inner join datesinfo dt on  os.caption0=dt.serverinfo where os.caption0 not like '%Server%' and  os.caption0 not like '%Windows 10%'
group by dt.Servicepack,serverinfo,dt.servicepacksupportenddate,dt.extendedsupportenddate



select * from #temptable
```

data in sccm tables is wrong so to correct that we have to taken enterprise and entreprise as same

data in datesinfo table

```
serverinfo  LifecyclestartDate  ExtendedSupportEnddate  servicepacksupportenddate   servicepack
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 2009-10-22  NULL    2020-01-14  Service Pack 1
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard   2009-10-22  NULL    2020-01-14  Service Pack 1
Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Standard    2008-05-06  NULL    2011-04-09  Service Pack 1
Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Enterprise  2008-05-06  NULL    2020-01-14  Service Pack 2
Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Standard    2008-05-06  NULL    2020-01-14  Service Pack 2
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard  2012-10-30  NULL    2023-10-10  Service Pack 2
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard   2012-10-30  NULL    2023-10-10  Service Pack 2
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacenter    2012-10-30  2018-10-09  2023-10-10  
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 2012-10-30  2018-10-09  2023-10-10  
Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard  2016-10-15  2022-01-11  2027-01-12  
Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter    2016-10-15  2022-01-11  2027-01-12  
Microsoft® Windows Vista™ Enterprise    2007-01-25  NULL    2010-04-13  
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise  2007-01-25  NULL    2020-04-13  Service Pack 1
Microsoft Windows 8.1 Entreprise    2013-11-13  NULL    2023-07-11  
Microsoft® Windows Vista™ Entreprise    2007-01-25  NULL    2010-04-13  
Microsoft Windows 7 Entreprise  2007-01-25  NULL    2020-04-13  Service Pack 1
Microsoft Windows 8.1 Entreprise    2013-11-13  NULL    2023-07-11  
Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 1900-01-01  1900-01-01  2019-10-08  15063
Microsoft Windows 10 Entreprise 1900-01-01  1900-01-01  2019-10-08  15063
Microsoft Windows 10 Entreprise 1900-01-01  1900-01-01  2020-04-14  16299
Microsoft Windows 10 Entreprise 1900-01-01  1900-01-01  2020-11-10  17134
Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 1900-01-01  1900-01-01  2020-11-10  17134
Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 1900-01-01  1900-01-01  2021-05-10  17763
Microsoft Windows 10 Entreprise 1900-01-01  1900-01-01  2021-05-10  17763
```

Comment: What do you mean you need to "merge" them?   What result do you want to get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server HTH

Comment: You should probably show us the query which generated that result set, assuming it is not just a simple `SELECT *`.

Comment: yes its query from where iam getting this result set i have pasted in questions

Answer (score 0):

Take your query and `GROUP BY serverinfo`. Use aggregation functions in the rest of the columns: eg sum(count1) of you want all count1 to be summed, and max(csdversion) if you are SURE all cdsversions will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `GROUP BY` query, taking the sum of the count, and aggregating by all other columns:

```
SELECT
    SUM(count1) AS count1,
    serverinfo,
    csdversion,
    extend,
    servicepackdate,
    piecolor
FROM #temp_table
GROUP BY
    serverinfo,
    csdversion,
    extend,
    servicepackdate,
    piecolor;
```

Comment: Asking a question the way you did, leaving out critical information, usually won't work either.  This is a good attempt, given that you left out the query.