# Dynamically generate sql statement based on metadata about the data being queried

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I would like to dynamically query data that is staged as a long string by defining how to read the string and how to split it up.

So I can define the data with the following elements

```
FIELD_NAME              VARCHAR2(30)          NOT NULL,
DATA_TYPE               VARCHAR2(20)          NOT NULL,
COLUMN_ID               NUMBER                NOT NULL,
FIELD_START_POS         NUMBER,
FIELD_END_POS           NUMBER,
FIELD_LEN               NUMBER,
ROW_TYPE                VARCHAR2(10),
DATE_MASK               VARCHAR2(12)
```

sample data in this table

[image]

can I take that info to create a select that would look something like

```
SELECT CASE cd.data_type
           WHEN 'DATE'
           THEN
               TO_DATE (SUBSTR (sd.source_text, cd.field_start_pos, cd.field_len), cd.date_mask)
           WHEN 'NUMBER'
           THEN
               TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (sd.source_text, cd.field_start_pos, cd.field_len))
           ELSE
               TRIM (SUBSTR (sd.source_text, cd.field_start_pos, cd.field_len))
       END
           AS cd.field_name
  FROM staged_data sd, column_definitions cd
```

I am having difficulties trying to tie the 2 together.

I know I could pivot the column names in the definition out like so:

```
SELECT *
  FROM column_definitions 
  PIVOT (max(field_name) FOR column_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20))
```

but this still results in many rows

My goal is to generate this statement so that is can be run via the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE so it could work for many different files just by defining how to read the string.

I also have the need to read different row types hence the row_type column which will be defined for the same file but had their own column order and columns.

---

So I have been able to generate a string that is the select I am looking for based on the metadata about the staged file like this:

```
DECLARE
    select_items   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (  SELECT *
                  FROM column_definitions
                 WHERE file_pk = 1 AND row_type = 1
              ORDER BY column_id)
    LOOP
        IF c.data_type = 'NUMBER'
        THEN
            select_items :=
                   select_items
                || 'CASE WHEN is_number(SUBSTR(row_data,'
                || c.field_start_pos
                || ','
                || c.field_len
                || ')) = ''TRUE'' THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(row_data,'
                || c.field_start_pos
                || ','
                || c.field_len
                || ')) ELSE NULL END AS '
                || c.field_name
                || ',';
        ELSIF c.data_type = 'DATE'
        THEN
            select_items :=
                   select_items
                || 'CASE WHEN ISDATE(SUBSTR(row_data,'
                || c.field_start_pos
                || ','
                || c.field_len
                || '))=''true'' THEN TO_DATE(SUBSTR(row_data,'
                || c.field_start_pos
                || ','
                || c.field_len
                || '),'''
                || c.date_mask
                || ''') ELSE NULL END AS '
                || c.field_name
                || ',';
        ELSE
            select_items :=
                   select_items
                || 'TRIM(SUBSTR(row_data,'
                || c.field_start_pos
                || ','
                || c.field_len
                || ')) AS '
                || c.field_name
                || ',';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    select_items := SUBSTR (select_items, 1, LENGTH (select_items) - 1);

    select_items :=
           'SELECT '
        || select_items
        || ' FROM STAGED_FILE where row_type=1 AND rownum <= 1000;';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (select_items);
END;
```

this spits out something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN is_number (SUBSTR (row_data, 1, 1)) = 'TRUE'
           THEN
               TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (row_data, 1, 1))
           ELSE
               NULL
       END
           AS REC_TYPE_IND,
       SUBSTR (row_data, 11, 4)   AS SRVC_LOC,
       CASE
           WHEN ISDATE (SUBSTR (row_data, 15, 8)) = 'true'
           THEN
               TO_DATE (SUBSTR (row_data, 15, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')
           ELSE
               NULL
       END
           AS BEGIN_DT,
       CASE
           WHEN ISDATE (SUBSTR (row_data, 23, 8)) = 'true'
           THEN
               TO_DATE (SUBSTR (row_data, 23, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')
           ELSE
               NULL
       END
           AS END_DT,
       SUBSTR (row_data, 31, 50)  AS ID,
       SUBSTR (row_data, 101, 2)  AS COUNTY_CD,
       SUBSTR (row_data, 103, 30) AS ADDR_LN_1,
       SUBSTR (row_data, 133, 30) AS ADDR_LN_2,
       SUBSTR (row_data, 163, 18) AS CITY,
       SUBSTR (row_data, 181, 2)  AS STATE_CD,
       CASE
           WHEN is_number (SUBSTR (row_data, 183, 5)) = 'TRUE'
           THEN
               TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (row_data, 183, 5))
           ELSE
               NULL
       END
           AS ZIP_CD,
       CASE
           WHEN is_number (SUBSTR (row_data, 188, 4)) = 'TRUE'
           THEN
               TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (row_data, 188, 4))
           ELSE
               NULL
       END
           AS ZIP_CD4,
       CASE
           WHEN is_number (SUBSTR (row_data, 192, 10)) = 'TRUE'
           THEN
               TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (row_data, 192, 10))
           ELSE
               NULL
       END
           AS PHONE_NUM
  FROM staged_FILE
 WHERE row_type = 1 AND ROWNUM <= 1000;
```

Now off to solve how to dynamically create an associative array to stuff the data into or another way to work with the data.

Comment: this might help as an alternative to pivoting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server

Comment: A `case` expression only returns a single type, so your `case` isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you use a `CASE` statement. Your first expression has a `DATE` datatype, the second has `NUMBER` and the third is a `VARCHAR2`. From the documentation:

> For a simple CASE expression, the expr and **all comparison_expr values
>   must either have the same datatype** or must all have a
>   numeric datatype.

Basically, you can't do this because there's no way to know at compile time what the datatype of the `field_name` column is.

This is not a straightforward problem to solve, since you don't know what your datatype is going to be until runtime. Even once you get a dynamic SQL statement, what sort of variable are you going to select the data *into*?

I think you're basically going to have to:

1. Using `column_definitions`, construct a **string** that contains a SQL statement appropriate for the data type in question.
2. Create a `TYPE` that contains members of all the possible resulting data types.
3. Use either `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `DBMS_SQL` to parse and execute that string, then fetch the result into an instance of that type.

You may actually be best off not doing this via SQL at all. Instead, I would probably do the following:

1. Get the data type of interest from `column_definitions`.
2. Use `SUBSTR` to extract the region of interest from the string in staged_data.
3. Do something like:

.

```
l_token := SUBSTR (sd.source_text, cd.field_start_pos, cd.field_len);
IF l_datatype = 'DATE' THEN
    l_date := TO_DATE( l_token, 'yyyy-mm-dd' );
ELSIF l_datatype = 'NUMBER' THEN
    l_number := TO_NUMBER( l_token);
....
END IF;
```

I would not expect high performance from this sort of approach.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I do realize a CASE has to return the same datatype from each outcome.  The code above was just an interpretation of what I was trying to do.

I am currently trying with the dbms_sql package.  I am working in a 18c database so I need to explore some of the newer built in packages.