# Move an object up and separate based on item

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have the following problem:

```
Apple  | Document 1 | 5
Orange | Document 2 | 4
Apple  | Document 3 | 7
```

What I would like to happen with a query is the following:

```
Apple  | Document 1 | Document 3 | 12
Orange | Document 2              | 7
```

Is there a function that does this for you?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2017 you can use `STRING_AGG` function along with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT fruit, STRING_AGG(document, '|') AS documents, SUM(value) AS total
FROM t
GROUP BY fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use combination of `Stuff and XML Path` if you are working on Pre SQL Server 2017

```
SELECT fruit, 
    abc = STUFF(
                 (SELECT '|' + doc FROM test t1
                     WHERE t1.fruit = t2.fruit FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
               ), SUM(value)
FROM test t2 GROUP BY fruit
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce52e/2

The `STUFF and XML PATH` is very explained well over here

[How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: Great, I'll give this a shot in a few days. Thanks. Is there a specific terminology, or is there a name to this movement that would better aid my google-fu?