# How does declaring and using a variable in TSQL select statement give a different result

Tags: sql-server

I want to get a list of comma separated customer names. The below code only returns the last name

```
DECLARE @vfirstname NVARCHAR(500), @vdelimiter NVARCHAR(1)
SET @vdelimiter=','

SELECT @vfirstname = FirstName + @vdelimiter
FROM dbo.Customer c

SET @vfirstname = LEFT(@vfirstname, LEN( @vfirstname ) - 1);    
PRINT @vfirstname
```

I was able to fix it introducing the below statements (with help from google):

```
 SET @vfirstname ='' 
 SELECT @vfirstname = @vfirstname + FirstName + @vdelimiter
 FROM dbo.Customer c
```

But I am unable to understand the need to do this , how does the select statement really work in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you need without the substring function, the 
Select ','  is your delimiter

The stuff function removes the first comma/delimiter from the list for you using the XML path

```
-- use stuff instead of substringb
Select STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + FirstName
    FROM dbo.Customer
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1,'') 
FROM dbo.Customer
-- if you want a space after comma, need to update the STUFF to be 1, 2
```

Comment: I would recommend this method instead as well. For further reading, try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server

Comment: Can also use [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you have a new enough version.