# How to roll up multiple rows into a single row and column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I referenced [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server) and others stacks

This is what I have done:

```
SELECT 
    ReportDate,  
    ReportID = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(t1.ReportID AS varchar(50)) 
                      FROM BackEndEfficiency t1
                      WHERE t1.ReportID = t2.ReportID
                      FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM
    BackEndEfficiency t2
GROUP BY
    ReportDate
```

Error:

> Column 'BackEndEfficiency.ReportID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why am I getting this error as I want the `ReportDate` to be grouped by?

Example of data structure

```
ReportDate  ReportID
--------------------
2020-03-11  30
2020-03-11  31
2020-03-16  32
2020-03-16  33
```

I would like to get this output:

```
ReportDate  ReportID
--------------------
2020-03-11  30,31
2020-03-16  32,33
```

Comment: please do not post image, post as text please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `ReportDate` for the correlation clause.  I would recommend:

```
select bee.ReportDate,
       stuff((select ',' + CAST(t1.ReportID as varchar(50)) 
              from BackEndEfficiency bee2
              where bee2.ReportDate = bee.ReportDate
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') 
from (select bee.ReportDate
      from BackEndEfficiency bee
     ) bee;
```

Comment: Should be using Date = Date instead of ID = ID. My mistake.