# How to reverse string in column a word by word?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a `varchar(50)` column `'Relation'` having more than 1000 rows of data like:

```
 P1_P10_P45_P20
 P1_P14_P5_P22
 P1_P3
 P3_P4_P5_P2_P100_P2_P1
```

I want the output to have reverse order:

```
 P20_P45_P10_P1
 P22_P5_P14_P1
 P3_P1
 P1_P2_P100_P2_P5_P4_P3
```

Could you please help me achieve this in single query?

Comment: Hello, this isn't a code writing service. You should first attempt to solve the issue yourself and then ask about specific issues (or the issue as a whole, but show your attempt to solve it). Check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is your SQl Server version?

Comment: Fix your data model!  The root problem is that you are storing multiple values in a string.

Comment: SQL Server v18.5

Comment: @Aditi v18.5 is the version of the SQL Server Management Studion (a client tool). What is the SQL Server version (what does `SELECT @@VERSION;` return)? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov version 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the stored strings using a splitter, that returns the substrings and the position of each substring. After that you can easily build the desired output.

If you use SQL Server 2017+, you may try a JSON-based approach. You need to transform each string into a valid JSON array (for example `P1_P10_P45_P20` into `["'P1","P10","P45","P20"]`), parse this array as a table with `OPENJSON()` and join the rows with `STRING_AGG()` to generate the expected output:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (Relation varchar(50))
INSERT INTO Data (Relation)
VALUES
   ('P1_P10_P45_P20'),
   ('P1_P14_P5_P22'),
   ('P1_P3'),
   ('P3_P4_P5_P2_P100_P2_P1')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT c.Relation
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT STRING_AGG([value], '_') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]) DESC)
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(d.Relation, '_', '","'), '"]'))
) c (Relation)
```

Result:

```
Relation
----------------------
P20_P45_P10_P1
P22_P5_P14_P1
P3_P1
P1_P2_P100_P2_P5_P4_P3
```

Answer (score 2):

Aditi you can use a Tally table to find all _ and then join them back using S[TUFF + FOR XML PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server) combination like below.

I recommend that you read about Tally tables at earliest possible time [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Also the demo link is [here](https://rextester.com/XVISX34463)

```
--create table yourtable(Relation nvarchar(50));
--insert into yourtable values 
-- ('P1_P14_P5_P22'),
--   ('P1_P3'),
--   ('P3_P4_P5_P2_P100_P2_P1'), ('P1_P3'),
--   ('P3_P4_P5_P2_P100_P2_P1');


;WITH Tally AS (
   SELECT 1 as Num
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Num + 1 FROM Tally  WHERE Num < 51
    )
,
InputSet AS
(
 select *, RN=row_number() over (order by (select 1)) from yourtable
    )
,TempSet AS
(
      SELECT 
        Relation, 
        Num,
        RN,
        partBetweenUnderscore = SUBSTRING(Relation, Num, ISNULL(LEAD(Num) OVER (Partition by RN ORDER BY Num ASC),LEN('_'+Relation)+1)-Num-1)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *  
        FROM InputSet CROSS JOIN Tally 
        WHERE CHARINDEX('_','_'+Relation,Num)=Num
     )T
 )
SELECT 
   Relation,
    NewRelation = STUFF(
                    (SELECT '_' + T1.partBetweenUnderscore FROM TempSet T1 WHERE T1.RN=T2.RN ORDER BY T1.Num DESC FOR XML PATH ('') 
                        ),1,1,'')
FROM TempSet T2
GROUP BY RN, Relation
```

Comment: If the column 'Relation' have more than 1 rows it shows error 'Invalid parameter length passed to left or substring function'.

Here is the modification done in your link by inserting another row:
[link](https://rextester.com/JVAX56882)

Comment: @Aditi updated my answer to support multiple rows.  The last edit also handles duplicate relation column data

Answer (score 0):

First all of the prievious comments are correct, especially that this is a data model problem.  Here is a very kludgy solution.  I offer it because you only have 1000 records.  This is not efficient, nor will it scale up.  The following works on MS SQL Server 2017.

```
Drop table if exists Relation   
create table Relation (Relation varchar(50))
INSERT INTO Relation (Relation)
VALUES
    ('P1_P10_P45_P20'),
    ('P1_P14_P5_P22'),
    ('P1_P3'),
    ('P3_P4_P5_P2_P100_P2_P1');



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Rev
create table Rev (Relation varchar(50), Rev varchar(50))
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Z
create table Z (token varchar(50))
declare @Reverse varchar(50)
set @Reverse = ''

declare @token varchar(50)
declare @Relation varchar(50)
declare cur cursor for select * from Relation
open cur
fetch next from cur into @Relation
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin   
    with T(Relation, starts, pos) as (
    select @Relation, 1, charindex('_', @Relation)
    union all
    select @Relation, pos + 1, charindex('_', @Relation, pos + 1)
    from T
    where pos > 0)
    insert into Z select substring(@Relation, starts, case when pos > 0 then pos - starts else len(@Relation) end) token
    from T
    declare cur2 cursor for select token from Z
    open cur2
    fetch next from cur2 into @token
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            set @Reverse =  @token + '_' + @Reverse  
            fetch next from cur2 into @token
        end
        close cur2
        deallocate cur2
        set @Reverse = (select left(@Reverse,len(@Reverse)-1))
        insert into Rev select @Relation, @Reverse
        set @Reverse = ''
        delete Z
    fetch next from cur into @Relation
end;
close cur
deallocate cur
select * from Rev



SELECT @@version
```