# Concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The script shown here work in SQL Server but NOT in SNOWFLAKE SQL.  What is the equivalent in SNOWFLAKE SQL?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ST2.SubjectID, 
    SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + ST1.StudentName AS [text()]
               FROM dbo.Students ST1
               WHERE ST1.SubjectID = ST2.SubjectID
               ORDER BY ST1.SubjectID
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 2, 1000) [Students]
FROM 
    dbo.Students ST2
```

RESULTS FROM SAMPLE BELOW: IT CONCATENATES TEXT FROM ALL THE ROWS INTO A SINGLE TEXT STRING BY ID

I tried the above in SQL Server and it worked, however, I need to use a datawarehouse in Snowflake and snowflake doesn't use XML PATH. They have XMLGET but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: The equivalent of SQL Server [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html). The XML is an old way to concatenate string on SQL Server before the String_Agg function was introduced, therefore when translating code between two DBs the focus should be on the intent/behavior and not 1:1 translation of code.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want `listagg`. Implementation should look like this

```
select SubjectId, listagg(distinct StudentName,',') as Students
from your_table
group by SubjectId;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Lukasz mentions, the `FOR XML PATH ('')` syntax in SQL Server was a common way to implement string aggregation before the existence of an explicate## Heading ## operator in later SQL Server versions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212160/9525344) answer describes how it works in SQL Server.

If you are on a version of SQL Server that support the operator, then you could change your code to use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) and test that it gives the correct results on SQL Server. Then to migrate to Snowflake, you can simply change the `STRING_AGG` keyword to [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html).

If you have a lot of such SQL to convert, you might consider using tooling that will recognize such specialized syntax and convert it to the simpler form.

Answer (score 0):

so if your source data look like:

```
    select * from values
    (1, 'student_a'),
    (1, 'student_b'),
    (1, 'student_c'),
    (2, 'student_z'),
    (2, 'student_a')
```

both the old code and Phil's code will have a random order, the original code did an `ORDER BY SubjectID` but that is the value being grouped.

In snowflake an order like this can be done with `within group (order by studentname)`

so Phil's answer becomes:

```
select 
    subjectid, 
    listagg(distinct studentname,',') within group (order by studentname) as students
from students
group by subjectid;
```

which then gives the results:

| SUBJECTID | STUDENTS |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | student_a,student_z |
| 1 | student_a,student_b,student_c |