# Question marks appearing in query result when I concatenate values from multiple rows

Tags: t-sql, string-aggregation

I am trying to concatenate values in a column when those values correspond to the same ID number.  Here's an example of the data:

[image]

The query result I want is this:

[image]

Here is the code I tried to achieve this result.

```
SELECT column1, 
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + column2
              FROM your_table t2
              WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS concatenated_values
FROM your_table t1
GROUP BY column1;
```

This code returns question marks (e.g., "????") in many rows.  I don't want this.  Please help.

Comment: ???? normally would indicate that the data is `nvarchar` and somewhere along the way you are converting it as `varchar` and it doesn't support all the characters. But you haven't given us enough code/explanation

Comment: DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT, names VARCHAR(5))
INSERT @t (id,names)
VALUES
(1, 'A'),(1, 'B'),(2, 'A'),(3, 'B')

SELECT id, STRING_AGG(Names, ', ') 
FROM @t
GROUP BY id;

Comment: I suspect selecting elements using FOR XML PATH returns NVARCHAR strings, not VARCHAR. If you can't make your database contain NVARCHAR, try converting the results with [(... FOR XML PATH ... TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212041/22437).